# Product Image not coming below

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm working on [this](http://toolskaart.com/index.php/boring-tools/sclcl-r/s06f-sclcl-04-f3.html) website. The related products are displaying, but the image is not coming below the title. It is moving a bit right. I tried including `<br />`. But the look will blow away. Please suggest some modification so that the image comes exactly below. the code goes like this

```
<?php 
    $related_prods = $_product->getRelatedProductIds();
?>
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach($related_prods as $related){
    ?>
    <li style="display: inline; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <?php    $_rel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($related);
        echo $_rel->getName()."\r\n"."\r\n"."\r\n";

    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_rel->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_rel->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_rel, 'thumbnail')->resize(84, 81) ?>" width="120" height="120" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_rel->getName()) ?>" /></a>
        &nbsp;
        &nbsp;
    </li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

Another is that, in that page, in additional information the product is showing the sku code of product. How to make it invisible in admin page.

Comment: increase `li` width and use `float: left` for all the li's except last.

Comment: where did you put `<br/>`?

Answer (score 1):

```
.product-image{
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

Hope that helps

:)